# How I can enter the name for a right click option selected in Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

My scenario is I have to right click on one web element and select the second option which as a result creates a new child location and application by default gives a name to newly created child location (example Default (1)).
My target is to change the default name to a customized name i.e change Default (1) to Child (1).

I am successfully able to right click and then select the second option but fails to rename the child location to customized name.

The html code looks like:

```
<ul class="rtUL">
    <li class="rtLI rtFirst rtLast">
        <div class="rtTop">
        <ul class="rtUL">
            <li class="rtLI rtLast">
                <div class="rtBot rtSelected">
                    <span class="rtIn">Default (1)</span>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My script code looks like:

```
WebElement rootLocation = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='Testlocation']//span[contains(text(),'RL')]"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.contextClick(RL).build().perform();
WebElement elementOpen = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Create Child"));
elementOpen.click();
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you post html snippet of menu which comes after right click? I think, because of that locator problem only it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default name to a customized name after successfully right click by using `JavascriptExecutor` as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Default (1)')]")));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].textContent = arguments[1]", el, "Child (1)")
```

Hope it will work after successfully right click to change text of newly created child from `Default (1)` to `Child (1)`...:)

Comment: Gaurav, I used ur code and it replaces the Default (1) to Child (1) (I see getting it changed when the script runs) but the issue is when page refresh the name is still coming as Default (1). I tried doing build and perform but no success. Now the code is Actions action = new Actions (driver);
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
  WebElement el1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Default (1)')]"));
  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].textContent = arguments[1]", el1, "Child (1)");
  action.click(el1).build().perform();

Comment: @reena yeah i know its change at runtime only for testing purpose and will not effect permanently...  do you want changes should effect permanently??

Comment: @reena Could you share me the steps how does change default name manually thats why i could provide you the solution which will effect permanently

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for my problem with help from a frnd.

```
    WebElement newLoc1 =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Default (1)')]"));
    Actions mAction = new Actions(driver);
    mAction.moveToElement(newLoc1);
    mAction.contextClick(newLoc1).build().perform();// This will do right click
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Click to Rename')]")).click();//This will select the renaming option from the right click options
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Default (1)']")).sendKeys(Keys.HOME,Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT,Keys.END),"newloc");//This will delete the Default name ie Default (1) and change the name to a new name ie newloc
```

`